# Twitter Log in with Localhost

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

So I am trying to make my users connect their twitter accounts to my website's accounts by making them log in to twitter. How I want it to work is that, they will click a button it will pop-up (or redirect to) a twitter page where they can login. Then I will get their twitter username (yes only the username).

How can I achieve this? I would really appreciate an example, so far the tutorials and guides in official twitter website have not really helped me that much.

I am using only php and javascript and the website is running on localhost. I have created a developer account on twitter but I am not sure what my "Website Url"(It does not accept http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1) and "Callback Url" should be.

Thank you in advance, and sorry if this something very basic or simple.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this local as domain names are required for security purposes when setting up the account to allow 3rd party login access.

Comment: Really? Is there any way to test twitter log in wihtout a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please note - any callback URL that you use with the POST oauth/request_token endpoint will have to be whitelisted within the Twitter app settings in the app details page of developer portal
>
> From: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens

Twitter will not whitelist `localhost` - so you will need a temporary domain while testing.

Answer (score 4):

suppose you want to access "http://localhost:8000", then you have to put "http://www.localhost:8000" in the domain.

just by adding "www" it will allow you to access your localhost.
this worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).